# Calling parent function in kv, from screen class

Tags: python, class, methods, kivy

I have a method in `script1.py` with a function `function1` and a screen class `Screen`, and its accompanied kv file `gui.kv`. I would like to call `function1` in `gui.kv`, within the `Screen` class.

Only problem is that I do not know how. `root.` Will call the Screen class, but I would like to call from the broader spectrum `script1.py` since that's where `function1` is defined.

How would I do this?

EDIT:

I'll show what I mean in a more applied piece of code:

**Script1.py**

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

def function1(digit):
    return digit + 2

class Screen(Screen):
    pass
```

**gui.kv**

```
<Screen>:
    FloatLayout:
        <I would like to call function1(digit) here>
```

I've tried `root.function1(digit)` but that does not work since `root` is the `Screen` class. I've also tried `super().root.function(digit)` to access the entire script, but neither did that work.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I actually tried to make my question as straight-forward and non-context-related as possible.

I'll add some basic script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, python/kivy are extremely context related, that is why we ask for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Given what you have provided, You can access `function1` from the `kv` file like this:

```
#:import Script1 Script1

<Screen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: str(Script1.function1(3)
```

See the [kivy.lang documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#import-package). Note that this uses the value returned from `function1()` at the time the `kv` file is loaded and does not set up any bindings. This also assumes that all the files are in the same folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This worked. Main issue was importing.